# getFromLocationName from Geocoder returns always null

Tags: android, google-maps, coordinates, geocoding, latitude-longitude

I know that this question has been asked many times, but I cannot find a solution: whatever I try, I can't retrieve LatLng from a given address. Could you take a look at my code in order to guide me and find a solution? I'm getting crazy here...

Here is the code:

```
public LatLng getCoordinates(String address){

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext);
    List<Address> addresses;

    double latitude=0;
    double longitude=0;
    LatLng coordinates;

    try {

        if(geocoder.isPresent()){
            System.out.println("Geocoder present!");
            //Geocoder is actually present
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Geocoder NOT present!");

        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(address, 1);                

        /* I tried this too, but it didn't work:
        int count=0;
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(address, 10);
        while(addresses.size()==0 && count<10){
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(address, count);
            count++;
        }
        */

        //This instruction throws the exception
        System.out.println("addresses variable = "+addresses.get(0).toString());

        System.out.println("addresses size="+addresses.size());
        if(addresses.size() > 0) {
            latitude= addresses.get(0).getLatitude();
            longitude= addresses.get(0).getLongitude();
            // latitude= addresses.get(count).getLatitude();
            // longitude= addresses.get(count).getLongitude();
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    coordinates = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
    return coordinates;
}
```

And here is the printStackTrace result:

```
02-08 17:33:50.922 9152-9152/com.clb.apokalos.todolistas W/System.err: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
02-08 17:33:50.922 9152-9152/com.clb.apokalos.todolistas W/System.err:     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
02-08 17:33:50.932 9152-9152/com.clb.apokalos.todolistas W/System.err:     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
02-08 17:33:50.932 9152-9152/com.clb.apokalos.todolistas W/System.err:     at com.clb.apokalos.todolistas.GPSTracker.getCoordinates(GPSTracker.java:178)
02-08 17:33:50.932 9152-9152/com.clb.apokalos.todolistas W/System.err:     at com.clb.apokalos.todolistas.GeofenceMainActivity.populateGeofenceList(GeofenceMainActivity.java:365)
02-08 17:33:50.942 9152-9152/com.clb.apokalos.todolistas W/System.err:     at com.clb.apokalos.todolistas.GeofenceMainActivity.onCreate(GeofenceMainActivity.java:100)
02-08 17:33:50.942 9152-9152/com.clb.apokalos.todolistas W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5024)
02-08 17:33:50.942 9152-9152/com.clb.apokalos.todolistas W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
02-08 17:33:50.952 9152-9152/com.clb.apokalos.todolistas W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2042)
02-08 17:33:50.952 9152-9152/com.clb.apokalos.todolistas W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2103)
02-08 17:33:50.952 9152-9152/com.clb.apokalos.todolistas W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:137)
02-08 17:33:50.952 9152-9152/com.clb.apokalos.todolistas W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1211)
02-08 17:33:50.962 9152-9152/com.clb.apokalos.todolistas W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-08 17:33:50.972 9152-9152/com.clb.apokalos.todolistas W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-08 17:33:50.972 9152-9152/com.clb.apokalos.todolistas W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4842)
02-08 17:33:50.972 9152-9152/com.clb.apokalos.todolistas W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-08 17:33:50.972 9152-9152/com.clb.apokalos.todolistas W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-08 17:33:50.972 9152-9152/com.clb.apokalos.todolistas W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
02-08 17:33:50.982 9152-9152/com.clb.apokalos.todolistas W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
02-08 17:33:50.982 9152-9152/com.clb.apokalos.todolistas W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thank you all!

**EDIT (SOLVED)**: Found the problem! I was giving the address in the form of "*ShopName, address, city*" (I was using informations gatered from a query to Google) and it didn't work, so I changed the string simply in the form of "*Address, city*" and now it works! Thanks again!

Comment: Have you tried debugging your geoCoder object? what does it contain?

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocationName(java.lang.String,%20int)) *Returns null or empty list if no matches were found or there is no backend service available*. Are you sure that the location name is correct and that you have Internet access?